# Number of times map application launched by external events in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, launch, android-intent

Is there any way to count number of times map application launched by external events in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

during OnCreate add 1 to the numberofTimes counter and commit.

```
OnCreate (Bundle bundle){
  mPref = getPreferences();
  int c = mPref.getInt("numRun",0);
  c++;
  mPref.edit().putInt("numRun",c).commit();

 }
```

OnPause method to check to see if the activity is being finish() or just being paused.

```
@Override
   protected void OnPause(){
     if(!onFinishing()){
     c = mPref.getInt("numRun",0);
     c--;
     mPref.edit().putInt("numRun",c).commit();
  }
  //Other pause stuff.
}
```

This covers all your scenarios:

```
1. user starts app/activity (+1)-> finishes app, exit with finish()
2. user starts app (+1) -> pause (-1) -> returns (+1)-> finish
3. user starts app (+1) -> pause (-1) -> android kills process (0) -> user returns to app (+1) -> user finish.
```

Comment: In my application i want to check how many times google-map has been launched by external events. Is it possible to monitor other application in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to count the number of times that google maps has been used.